# C program for speed of sound in air not giving correct results

Tags: c

The program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define s 1086

/* Function Prototypes */
void directions(void);
float temp(void);
float calc_speed(float temp);
void display(float temp, float calc_speed);

void main()
{
    float speed;
    float tempy;

    /* Calling Functions */
    directions();
    temp();
    speed = calc_speed(tempy);
    display(tempy, speed);
}

/* Sub Program for directions */
void directions(void)
{
    printf("Enter the temperature T in farienheit> ");
}

/* Sub program for temp */
float temp(void)
{
    float t;

    scanf("%f", &t);

    return(t);
}

/* Calculating speed */
float calc_speed(float temp)
{
    float ss;

    ss = s * (sqrt(5* temp +297)/(247));

    return(ss);
}

/* Displaying Results */
void display(float temp, float calc_speed)
{
    printf("The speed of sound at %f fareinhiet is : %f", temp, calc_speed);
}
```

The program instructions in the link below .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lelta.png)

Comment: Aside: please don't double-space the code. Although required for proof-reading, here it makes the code hard to read.

Comment: `sqrt(5* temp +297)/(247)` -> `sqrt((5* temp +297)/(247))`

Comment: *not giving correct results* may be considered unclear by a lot of people so it would be better if you could describe within the question body what you wanted to achieve and what you do get at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that the denominator should be inside the square root according to the instructions.

```
ss = s * (sqrt(5* temp +297)/(247));
```

should be

```
ss = s * (sqrt((5* temp +297)/(247)));
```

EDIT: Also as mentioned by the other answer your variable `tempy` was never initialized, you need to assign it with the return value of `temp()`.

```
tempy = temp();
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the user input here

```
float temp(void)
{
    float t;

    scanf("%f", &t);

    return(t);
}
```

But you don't do anything with the returned value

```
 temp();
 speed = calc_speed(tempy);
```

So you call Cacl_speed with an uninitialized value 
Try

```
tempy = temp();
speed = calc_speed(tempy);
```